# Call C#.net method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I Have Method in Code behind(C#) and Want to call this method inside the javascript.

My Code in C#

```
    private void StatusSet()
    {            
        List<StatusHandler> iListStatus = new List<StatusHandler>();

        iListStatus.Add(new StatusHandler('A', "Active"));
        iListStatus.Add(new StatusHandler('I', "InActive"));
        iListStatus.Add(new StatusHandler('L', "All"));

        if (hdnMode.Value == "i")
        {
            ddlStatus.DataSource = iListStatus.Take(2);
        }
        else
        {
            ddlStatus.DataSource = iListStatus.Take(3);
            if (lnkBtnUpdate1.Visible == true)
            {
                ddlStatus.DataSource = iListStatus.Take(2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Javascript :

```
function GetMode(modeIndex) {
    if (modeIndex == 'i') {
        StatusSet(); //How to Call in Javascript
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function/5828840#5828840

Answer (score 3):

You can't call this directly from javascript.
You must use Ajax.

EDIT:

Here you can see how to return a list as a JSON: [asp.net web forms json return result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364343/asp-net-web-forms-json-return-result/5364355#5364355)
Here you can see how to populate dropdown list: [jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

Comment: Then is it mandatory to make make method Static in server Side

Comment: yah, you have to make it static.