# How to make asp.net page returns JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

As mentioned in the question, How to make asp.net page returns data in JSON format ?

Comment: Check out the answer in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: Thanks, but I m sorry to duplicate the question, please can yo tell me how to search the required question before posting it ?

Comment: Are you using MVC or webforms?

Comment: @AdhamEnaya - When typing the question to post on SO, previous questions will be displayed, you can also use the search bar at the top of SO. In this case I just googled it and a stack overflow page came up with the answer :) I didnt want to duplicate the question which is why I just commented :)

Comment: I think the most relevant SO question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364343/asp-net-web-forms-json-return-result

Answer (score 3):

Insteed of response with `HTML` you can response with some JSON. What I think you want to do is adding an interface which can response with JSON.

With .NET you can use webservice which response in JSON format, have a look on this article:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether you are using webforms or MVC.

For webforms you can just write out the data that you want:

```
Response.Clear(); // not needed it you have an empty page markup
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
Response.End();
```

For MVC you can use the `Content` method in the action for the page:

```
return Content("{\"hello\":\"world\"}", "application(json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better for is to use [HttpHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001). It allows you to output anything you want. Alternative way is to use [web method](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx), but I'm not sure that its going to be easy to return json, not XML