# Is there a way in ASP.net to fetch data from database using Jquery(not using Webservices/WebMethods)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way in ASP.net to fetch data from database using Jquery Ajax Method. I know that i can easily access the data by creating a webservice and get it from there using Ajax.
What I want to know is that how can I get the data from simple class methods which accesses the database rather than creating a webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be is to write a HTTPHandler and call that handler using Jquery to retrieve the data.

Comment: Which way will be more faster by the way.
Calling Webservice or creating a HttpHandler?

Comment: Well I am not sure too sure about it but I do not think of any considerable difference in the responsiveness of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for a super-easy (lazy) way of doing a return straight from a public method defined in your aspx.cs file:

[asp.net web forms json return result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364343/asp-net-web-forms-json-return-result)

Example shows putting `[WebMethod]` and `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attributes on top of the method allows you to call directly from ajax client side request. Worth considering securing this method though to prevent calls from elsewhere!

Comment: But this ajax calls webservice/webmethod.I want to call the simple methods of class not webmethods.