# How to return value to AJAX from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Return Value From Code Behind To AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420565/how-to-return-value-from-code-behind-to-ajax)

This is my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'country_management.aspx/save',
        cache: false,
        data: "{'parameter':'paramValue'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.d);
                 if (data.d == "error") {
                    $('.success_box').hide();
                    $('.error_box').show();
                 }
                 else {
                    $('#name').val('');
                    $('.error_box').hide();
                    $('.success_box').show();
                 }
        }
});
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string save(string parameter)
{
    string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].Trim();
    return "error";
}
```

after writing the first line, return statement does not return anything to the AJAX.

Comment: You're not returning JSON, but a plain string. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364343/asp-net-web-forms-json-return-result.

Comment: Are you sure `QueryString["name"]` isn't returning `null`?

Comment: are you saying it errors out after this line?  
string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].Trim();

Comment: Did you -really- just create duplicate account for this purpose?

Comment: @Rohan I have returned "error" just to check if it is Returned or not.
If I don't write first line, return statement does return...

Comment: then id check what @Rawling said, confirm that QueryString["name"] actually exists.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks.
Actually my QueryString["name"] is null.
Let me know, How to pass parameters then??

Comment: The marked duplicate question now returns an error as the question is gone. Does this mean this is no longer a dupliate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the context of the whole application is kind of difficult to answer your question. (Does name get supplied from elsewhere in the app, you could make use of a session?)

But what is stopping you from passing the name through in the ajax call? Rather than just sending through'parameter':'paramValue'.

You have to remember your query string is supposed to contain the parameter you're looking for. at the moment it's looking something like.

http://www.somesite.com/country_management.aspx/save?parameter=paramValue

when you actually need

**e.g.**

http://www.somesite.com/country_management.aspx/save?parameter=paramValue&name=newName

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'country_management.aspx/save',
        data: { parameter:'paramValue', name: 'newName'},
        success: function (data) { 
           //do something with the response
        }         

});
```

**Codebehind**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string save(string parameter, string name)
{
    PerformSave(name, parameter);
    return "Data Saved!";
}
```

**TIP**

Try out this app. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It's extremely useful when you're working with things like ajax calls etc. Actually any web development. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't post any field or property "name"
If you do the ajax after clicked in a button inside form, data will be the form serialized.

Another thing is, why should you expect "name" var in query string, I don't see any url with aspx?name="any name"