# Autocomplete through Kendo UI in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm doing Autocomplete functionality using Kendo UI. I have the following script

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          alert("Script Start");
          $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
              dataTextField: "ProductName",
              filter: "contains",
              minLength: 3,
              dataSource: {
                  type: "odata",
                  serverFiltering: true,
                  serverPaging: true,
                  pageSize: 20,
                  transport: {
                      read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                  }
              }
          });
      });
        </script>
```

In read I'm getting the list of let say products. Now I want to do it through dataset that is already filled in my code behind. Is there any way to put dataset data in here to achieve this functionality through dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete [`Datasource`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/autocomplete#configuration-dataSource) expects simple javascripts object or javascript array or a kendo datasource instance. Somehow you have to manage some web method end point to [return json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364343/asp-net-web-forms-json-return-result) (preferred for model binding, can even return javascript array if you like). Just give your url to transport-read (read is simply a wrapper over $.ajax) and everything should be fine.

Comment: perfectly right. I did it by  dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource, by creating WebMethod behind. Perfectly working. :)